# Is bootstrap proper for building mobile app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to build a mobile web app. So I'm search around for ui framework. And I come across twitter bootstrap(people are mentioning it all the time).
From what I learned by shortly browsing through their website, I have the feeling that it's more for mobile **web sites**, but not proper for mobile **app**.
Because for the examples they showed, mostly they are trying to tell you how easy it is to build a web site which can adapted to all kinds of divices.
Please correct me if I'm wrong and advice some ui framework suitable for building mobile web apps(which can work nicely with angular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about Bootstrap.
[Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) responds to your criterias, but only works with the latest mobile OS.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is in fact [mobile-first and responsive by default](http://techcrunch.com/2013/07/28/bootstrap-3-goes-mobile-first-now-reportedly-powers-1-of-the-web/), making it perfectly suitable for use on mobile devices.

In your case, Bootstrap may or may not be what you're looking for. It's well supported and easy to use, but may be a little slower than you'd like, and can be a little constricting for mobile-only apps given that it is designed to work on both desktop and mobile.

[This article](http://html5hub.com/comparing-html5-mobile-ui-frameworks/#i.6pl1ewmr4eyb10) may be useful to you - it has a comparison of several frameworks and the pro/cons of each.